# Count the total number of multiple distinct occurrences in the same data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have the data frame `df`

```
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
0   'A' 'B' NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   'C' 'D' NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   'A' 'A' 'B' NaN NaN NaN
3   'A' 'B' 'C' NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I know that to count the number of `'B'` I have to use `(df == 'B').sum().sum()`.
Now suppose that I want to count how many elements contained in the list `v = ['B', 'C']` there are in the data frame. What could be a way of doing this?

Obviously `(df == 'B').sum().sum() + (df == 'C').sum().sum()` is okay but I need something more general.

`(df.isin(v)).sum().sum()` works fine.

Comment: have you tried `(df.isin(v)).sum().sum()`? because it works for me, see [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) on a dataframe

Comment: Yes, it works. At first it gave me an error but it didn't depend on this instruction. I edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `stack` the dataframe, which will create a series, then you can use `isin`, and call `sum()` at last.

```py
>>> df.stack().isin(['B', 'C']).sum()
5
```

Also, using `isin` directly on the dataframe will work fine calling `sum` twice:

```py
>>> df.isin(['B', 'C']).sum().sum()
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `stack` + `value_counts`

```
out = df.stack().value_counts()
Out[99]: 
'A'    4
'B'    3
'C'    2
'D'    1
dtype: int64
```

Then

```
out[v].sum()
```